# Data transfer failed in ajax jss

Tags: javascript, php

error: Undefined index: ten 
 Undefined index: giatri in php code
ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  var submit = $("button[id='lay']");

  //khi nút submit được click
  submit.click(function() a {
    var btn11 = $('#myBtn').html();
    var aa = $('#quatang').html();
    var gia;

    if (aa.trim() == "Bạn đã trúng thẻ quà tặng trị giá 10%") {
      gia = '10';
    } else if (aa.trim() == "Bạn đã trúng thẻ quà tặng trị giá 50%") {
      gia = '50';
    } else {
      alert('hah');
    }
    var data11 = 'ten=' + btn11.trim() + '&' + 'giatri=' + gia;
    alert(data11);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'magg.php',
      data: data11,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'false') {
          alert('Không có người dùng');
        } else {
          $('#thongbao').html(data);

        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

php code:

```
$ten = trim($_POST['ten']);
$giatri = trim($_POST['giatri']);
```

html code:

```
     <div>
        <form method="POST" action="magg.php">
              <button style="display: none;margin: auto;border:1px solid #25dac1; border-radius: 5px ; background: white;" id ="lay" >Lấy Mã</button>
        </form>
              <button id = "mohopqua" style="border:1px solid #25dac1; border-radius: 5px ; background: white;margin-top: 5px; ">Mở hộp quà</button>
```

Comment: Are you using `magg.php` to display the form and also respond to the AJAX?

Comment: as above code I sent data to magg.php to process the information but it didn't get the value from ajax so on the php side I didn't get the variable

Comment: But if `magg.php` is also loaded directly from the browser, the parameters won't be filled in and you'll get those errors.

Comment: So what do I do?

Comment: You can use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`. It combines `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: it doesn't work, I think it has a problem sending the data in ajax

Answer (score 0):

If the values of the parameters contain special characters, you need to encode them properly. It's best to use an object instead of a string, then jQuery will do the encoding for you.

```
var data11 = {ten: btn11.trim(), giatri: gia};
```

Comment: I don't think it's the character and the data11 variable I think it's right, I think it's the error of connecting to my magg.php file.